# Mark the default questions on Teams as "Accepted" since I am not the "Community"

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow-for-teams

Teams has about five default questions that are answered when you first set it up, for example:

[image: Question examples]

These are helpful but we'd like to essentially mark these closed.  I cannot since I am not the originator of the question, **Community** is.  For instance, I posted one of our own questions and we marked it as accepted essentially greening it out as such:

[image: example of Accepted]

But the questions that the community provided are not accepted, so it seems odd that I can never close them out (when in fact they are answered - and actually answered really well).

I think they should be marked as accepted otherwise there is no way to ever accept the answer.

@Jon Ericson
To help you see why this should be implemented (See my comments in your answer) if I go to the Stack Overflow homepage these questions won't go away from here:

[image: SO Home page]

### Third Issue

Sorry @Jon Ericson, I meant to post this picture:

[image: Unanswered Questions]

The link at the top of my team area says "Answer Questions" when I click this link it will ALWAYS show these Community created questions.  No one can accept them - hence why I keep stating that these should be marked as accepted by default.

Comment: Remember what the accept means ;)

Comment: I can't replicate the problem on the Teams I'm part of. I wonder if the questions will fall off the list over time or as new questions get asked. I have no idea if accepting the Community answers will matter at all.

Comment: In your team can't you arbitrarily set someone as the moderator and unilaterally close/delete the question? And can you set privileges to different thresholds? E.g. delete vote questions at 10 rep if you wanted?

Comment: For the "Unanswered Questions" view, can't you just upvote the answer to make it go away? Alternatively, it wouldn't hurt my feelings to just delete the questions. (Not that either will solve the deeper problem, of course.)

Comment: Bah @ deleting. I want to keep these for newcomers. Abd upvoting may get rid of them but but still...

Answer (score 8):

A potential workaround:

- Copy the question content, and ask it yourself.
- Answer your version of the question, either with the canned content or with alterations specific to your team.
- Vote (or get an admin) to close the original.

I'm unable to personally test this (I don't use teams yet) but, assuming the voting systems on SO and Teams are the same, it should do the trick.

Answer (score -14):

Thanks for mentioning they are answered really well! (I wrote the initial draft of the posts and got feedback from Donna who interviewed a bunch of beta Team users.) Primarily the goal of these questions is to:

1. Avoid the empty restaurant problem.
2. Give people who are not (yet) familiar with Stack Overflow for Teams some useful information.
3. Encourage the use of [meta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meta) for meta discussions.

I'm a bit resistant to accept the Community answer because of the third goal. I've already seen a team I happen to be part of use the "What kind of questions can I ask here?" question to give a custom answer that works better for that group than the generic answer. I anticipate people will also want to go into more detail about how their Team handles:

- tagging
- notifications
- integrations
- public vs. private information

Obviously, they can ask and answer another question, but it might be useful for some Teams to reuse the starter questions. If so, custom answers will certainly be better than the generic answer and should float to the top.

I think the deeper problem here is one we'll need to address at some point: **How will Teams manage accepted answers (and all the implied meaning) when the asker isn't around to change their vote?** We have this problem on public sites too, but I expect the semantics of accepted answers will be different in different organizations. For instance, you mentioned you wanted to "mark these closed" and I expect others will also want to somehow use accepted answers to show the question has been resolved. So it would be helpful for someone who isn't the asker to make that status change. Unlike on the public site, the checkmark might mean something other than "works for me!"

I don't have any solutions just yet, but I'll look for opportunities to research the issue and see how other Teams expect the accepted answer feature to work.

Comment: But even if a team does answer the question as you mentioned yourself.  No one will ever be able to accept that answer.  That is my issue with this.

Comment: `We have this problem on public sites too, but I expect the semantics of accepted answers will be different in different organizations.` simple fix to this and to my question.  Allow TEAM site admins to accept the answer.  Every team should have at max 1 or 2 admins...admins are trusted and so that trust should allow them to flag an answer as accepted.  In my questions case I should be able to ACCEPT the community questions.

Comment: @JonH: That's probably expedient, but I'd much rather find a way to do this without needing an admin (or mod on the public side) make the decision. Our assumption is that some admins will not be interested in managing content on the site. (Maybe user research will prove me wrong.) It would be better if there were some way for regular users to manage accepted answers when the asker is not around.

Comment: There is a way. The admin...you really don’t have any option do you?  I mean in my case community asked and community answered. Even if my team member answers the community question NO one can mark it accepted since we don’t have the user community. Why can there not be a simple change such that any community post allows accept by an admin?  I am in favor of allowing admins the right to accept answers, it doesnt mean they have to but they should be given the option. They are admins. Why can I, as an admin, mark the question deleted but not mark it accepted?

Comment: @JonH: Admins can delete questions because _any_ Teams user can delete a question. I could see letting any user accept an answer too, but it would be a bit strange when it comes to reputation. (Not that reputation matters much on Teams, but it would be odd if people gained and lost it because of someone unrelated to the question, or worse, another answerer transferring the checkmark.) In any case, the code assumes the asker is the only person who can accept an answer, so it might not be a trivial change.

Comment: The link at the top of my team says "Answer Questions" and these community questions will always be there when I click this link...because essentially no one can ever accept the answer.